# For uint64 type flag variable, unable to give it run time value in kubernetes deployment

Tags: go, kubernetes, deployment, yaml, compiler-flags

So I have  a Go binary with the flag

```
commitAfter = engine.Uint64("commitAfter", 1000, "Commit After Transactions")
```

And I am able to set it's value while executing the binary:

```
./mybinary -logger=*stdout -commitAfter=0
```

When I try to deploy it in kubernetes I'm unable to do so. Here is how I tried in my deployment file:

```
- command:
        - /opt/myBinary/mybinary
        - -logger
        - '*stdout'
        - -commitAfter=0
```

Similarly below also isn't working:

```
- command:
        - /opt/myBinary/mybinary
        - -logger
        - '*stdout'
        - -commitAfter
        - 0
```

It doesn't work with double quotes either. Is it just that because it is a Uint64 type or am I doing something wrong, as it is working when type is 'string' or 'int'. Please suggest.

Trying to set value in kubernetes deployment for a runtime argument for variable of type `uint64` in Go and it should have set it's value for that running instance of the kube pod.

Comment: What does happen?  What is the `engine` package here?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is a variable of type *flag.FlagSet, forgot to mention that. I want it to take value 0 on running the binary but it takes the flag default value i.e. 1000